# Différences entre « résoudre de faire qch » et « se résoudre à faire qch »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Je m'avise que [Wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/resoudre) n'est pas le dictionnaire magistral. Néanmoins, il allègue :

> - résoudre de faire qch: soutenu (décider)
>     *Il a résolu de changer de papier peint le mois prochain*.
> - se résoudre à faire qch: (se décider)
>     *Elle s'est enfin résolue à changer de voiture.*

Dans le Wiktionnaire,

- à [*résoudre*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9soudre) :

  > […] 6. Arrêter une décision ; décider une chose. […]
- à [*se résoudre*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_r%C3%A9soudre) :

  > 1. Se résigner, se faire une raison. […]

Dans *La Cathédrale* de Joris-Karl Huysmans :

> Dieu me pardonne, mais je crois que son logis est encore plus humide que le mien ; la vérité, c’est qu’il faudrait installer partout des calorifères et que **jamais on ne s’y résoudra**, faute d’argent.

[Page 345](http://books.google.com/books?id=2HAUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA345&dq=%22on+s%27y+r%C3%A9sout%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XqL1UsvXM4qfiQf52YDoCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22on%20s%27y%20r%C3%A9sout%22&f=false) de *L'école des pères* par Jean François Marmontel :

> On juge bien que dans ce joli cercle un engagement sérieux passait pour la plus haute extravagance. Quand **il y va** de sa fortune, disait-on, à la bonne heure, **on s'y résout**; mais un jeune homme, né avec beaucoup de bien, peut-il être assez sot ou assez fou pour se donner une chaîne? S’il n'aime point la femme qu’il épouse, c’est un fardeau qu’il s'impose à plaisir; et s’il aime, quel triste moyen pour lui plaire que celui d’être son
>   mari!

Mes questions :

1. Je ne saisis pas les différences (je vois que l'un est un verbe transitif et l'autre est pronominal). Par exemple, dans les deux passages, pourquoi ne pas utiliser sobrement « on (ne) résout (jamais) » ou « on (n')y résout (jamais) » ?
2. En outre, est-ce que le **y** dans **s'y résout** est relié au **y** dans **il y va**  ?
3. Étant néophyte, je trouve étonnant que *résoudre* est suivi de « de » alors que *se résoudre* est suivi de « à ». Y a t-il une raison ?

Comment: En français de France actuel, "on se résoud à": pronominal + à. Résoudre seul (transitif) signifie trouver la solution (à un problème, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google m'a révélé (l'existence) une réponse qui est plutôt fondéé sur *décider de/se décider à*, mais qui semble pertinent à ma question 3 ci-dessus, moyennant

---

<sub>p 369, *The semantics of ‘empty prepositions’ in French* (1996) by Kemmer and Shyldkrot, as part of *Cognitive Linguistics in the Redwoods: The Expansion of a New Paradigm in Linguistics* edited by Eugene H. Casad.</sub>

Let us look at a second example of this type of situation, illustrated 
in (10) with the verbs *décider/se décider* 'decide':
(10) a. Nous avons décidé de partir [sur-le-champ].    
'We decided to leave (right away).

b. Nous nous sommes [enfin] décidés à partir.
'We [finally] decided to leave/We [finally] made up our 
minds to leave.'

Here again there is a difference in the usage Of and de. (10a) would 
be most appropriate in a context with two characteristics: first, there is 
little or no temporal separation between the subjects' arriving at the 
decision and the carrying out of the decision. Second, the time that it  to reach the decision itself is irrelevant, although the implication here is that it was not a long process. The adverbial in brackets rein 
forces these characteristics of the context, but is not really necessary; 
the context given is simply the one most likely to induce In 
(10b), in contrast, the temporal separation between arriving at the decision and carrying it out is irrelevant; the subjects might act on their 
decision now or later, although the most neutral reading is probably 
that they will do it later. In regard to the amount of time taken to reach 
the decision, it is clear in this case that the decision was arrived at after a long process of deliberation. This effect remains with or without 
the reinforcing adverbial *enfin*. The subjects had to engage in a noticeable level of cognitive problem-solving, and overcome their uncertainties before the decision was reached. More intensive and pro- 
longed mental activity is therefore involved in arriving at the decision 
to carry out the event specified in the infinitive clause. Hence the 
appropriate English translation Of (10b) With 'made up their minds'. 
This greater level of goal-orientedness and mental participation of the 
subject occurs with the use of à and not de.

<sub>Source: p 182, *French prepositions à and de
in infinitival complements, 
A pragma-semantic analysis* (2008) by Lidia Fraczak, as part of *Adpositions ; Pragmatic, semantic and syntactic perspectives*  (2008) edited by D Kurzon, S Adler</sub>

It is relevant to quote the interpretation given by Réquédat (1980) of some
expressions depending on whether the verb is or not reflexive-marked (e.g. refuser
de / se refuser à – “to refuse”; décider de / se décider à – “to decide” / “to make
up one’s mind”; résoudre de / se résoudre à – “to resolve”), since the author notes
the existence of some kind of dilemma in case of reflexive forms. He considers
that, for the above three verbs, the simple form does not indicate anything else
than a refusal or a decision, whereas the reflexive form implies that this refusal
or decision was preceded by a time of hesitation. The reflexive form seems also
to indicate, according to the author, the importance of the interest or of the role
of the subject in the action. As for this second remark, one may consider indeed
that whenever there occurs a dilemma or a hesitation concerning an action, as
in the case of se décider à (“to make up one’s mind”), this involves the “interest”
or the “role of the subject in the action”, or “active concern” that is mentioned by
Cadiot (1997), or “intensive mental activity”, as Kemmer and Bat-Zeev Shyldkrot
(1995) put it.

Answer (score 1):

1. A nouveau les verbes pronominaux ont souvent un sens propre, plus ou moins déductible du sens de l'utilisation non pronominale.
2. Dans *on s'y résout*, *y* est un pronom dont l'antécédent est *un engagement sérieux*.  Dans *il y va de sa fortune*, *y* est un pronom sans antécédent, c'est un des cas où *y* donne un sens différent à un verbe et n'est plus réellement analysable (ça arrive aussi avec *en*). *y aller de qqch* signifie que ce qqch est en jeu.
3. Chercher des raisons autres qu'historique dans l'utilisation des prépositions est une quête vaine.

Answer (score 0):

La forme pronominale du verbe *résoudre* est toujours suivie de la préposition *à*.

Selon le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/resoudre), la forme « Se résoudre de » est d’un emploi vieilli. Mais il n’en explique pas l’usage.